# Sequelize .findOrCreate where Attribute is null

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm attempting to findOrCreate an object where an attribute is `null`:

```
    return models.Contact
        .findOrCreate({where : {
            Name : name, // name must be defined
            Phone :  {$eq:null},
            Email : {$eq:null},
        }})
```

I can not simply exclude the `Phone` and `Email` fields as that query may return contacts with the same name but with a phone number, which would not be accurate.

From what i have read about the documentation, this should be work (replacing `{$eq:null}` w/ `""` works). To my delight, however, I find the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: string violation: Phone 
cannot be an array or an object,
string violation: Email cannot be an array or an object
```

The `Contact` model is structured as the following:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Contact = sequelize.define('Contact', 
        {
            Name  : {
                type : DataTypes.STRING,
            },
            Phone  : {
                type : DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull : true,
            },
            Email  : {
                type : DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull : true,
            },
        },
    );
  return Contact;
};
```

What can I do to `.findOrCreate` a `Contact` where `Phone` and `Email` are `null`?

Comment: Are `operatorAliases` enabled?  Have you tried `Phone : {[Op.eq]: null }` ?

Comment: @spencer7593 I have indeed. Same exact error, so I don't think it comes down to operatorAliases